# Add XML Attribute to serialized class property

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I've seen an example that uses a wrapper class to do this, but i was wondering if there is a better (simpler) way.

My classes are as follows:

```
public class PartData
{
  public List<PartInfo> PartList { get; set; }
}


public class PartInfo
{
  public string PartNumber { get; set; }

  public string OEMNumbers { get; set; }

  public List<VehicleApplication> VehicleApplications { get; set; }
}


public class VehicleApplication
{

  public string Year { get; set; }

  public string Make { get; set; }

  public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Serialize code:

```
//serialize
private void serialize()
{
   PartData p = GetParts();
   SerializeClass(p);
}

public void SerializeClass(object instance)
{
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PartData));

  using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\TestFile.xml"))
  {
    serializer.Serialize(writer, instance);
  }
}
```

when serialized i get the following output:

```
 <PartData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PartList>
    <PartInfo>
      <PartNumber>12345</PartNumber>
      <OEMNumbers>14556, 14557, 14558, 14559</OEMNumbers>
      <VehicleApplications>
        <VehicleApplication>
          <Year>2001</Year>
          <Make>Ford</Make>
          <Model>F150</Model>
        </VehicleApplication>
        <VehicleApplication>
          <Year>2001</Year>
          <Make>Ford</Make>
          <Model>F150</Model>
        </VehicleApplication>
        <VehicleApplication>
          <Year>2001</Year>
          <Make>Ford</Make>
          <Model>F150</Model>
        </VehicleApplication>
        <VehicleApplication>
          <Year>2001</Year>
          <Make>Ford</Make>
          <Model>F150</Model>
        </VehicleApplication>
      </VehicleApplications>
    </PartInfo>
  </PartList>
</PartData>
```

Ideally i would like to make PartNumber an attribute like so:

```
 <PartData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PartList>
    <PartInfo>
      <PartNumber Id ="12345">
      <OEMNumbers>14556, 14557, 14558, 14559</OEMNumbers>
      <VehicleApplications>
        <VehicleApplication>
          <Year>2001</Year>
          <Make>Ford</Make>
          <Model>F150</Model>
        </VehicleApplication>
        <VehicleApplication>
          <Year>2001</Year>
          <Make>Ford</Make>
          <Model>F150</Model>
        </VehicleApplication>
        <VehicleApplication>
          <Year>2001</Year>
          <Make>Ford</Make>
          <Model>F150</Model>
        </VehicleApplication>
        <VehicleApplication>
          <Year>2001</Year>
          <Make>Ford</Make>
          <Model>F150</Model>
        </VehicleApplication>
      </VehicleApplications>
    </Partnumber>
    </PartInfo>
  </PartList>
</PartData>
```

I've tried adding:

```
public class PartInfo
{
  [XmlAttribute("Id")]
  public string PartNumber { get; set; }

  public string OEMNumbers { get; set; }

  public List<VehicleApplication> VehicleApplications { get; set; }
}
```

but creates:

```
<PartInfo Id="12345">
```

when i need:

```
<PartNumber Id="12345">
```

Comment: You probably mean `<PartInfo PartNumber='12345'>` (as in, not have `PartNumber` as 'wrapper' of `PartInfo` contents). If it's indeed the case, just add `[XmlAttribute]` to `PartNumber` property.

Comment: how are you currently serializing? looks like you could try `[XmlAttribute]`, (also please cut down your example, took me a while to figure out what was different!)

Comment: sorry for the rough explanation... what you both suggested yields: <PartInfo Id="12345"> when i would like <PartNumber Id="12345">

Comment: I think what you may have to do then is make a part number class that has a string (i.e another wrapper); edit to save you writing extra lines when using part number in code, just have your current part number, get and set the wrapper classes string value

Comment: what i really didn't want to do...

Comment: Do you want `<OEMNumbers>` and `<VehicleApplications>` to be children of `<PartNumber>`?

Comment: @pfyod  Yes, exactly what i want

Comment: all the data should be children of PartNumber

Comment: Then I guess that you indeed need to make `PartNumber` a class and have an `Id` property inside of it (mapped to attribute with `[XmlAttribute]`) inside of it - I am not aware of any `XmlSerializer` attribute that would do a transformation that you need.

Comment: without writing your own serializer, then the only way would be to make a sub detail class with part number as an `[XmlAttribute`

Comment: @pfyod - always 20 seconds ahead of me.. :D

Comment: @pfyod can you please elaborate on how you would re-structure my above classes?

Comment: each part number will have a list of oemNumbers and VehicleApplications

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the only way to achieve what you are trying to achieve

```
public class PartDetail
{
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string ID{ get; set; }

  public string OEMNumbers { get; set; }

  public List<VehicleApplication> VehicleApplications { get; set; }
}

public class PartInfo
{
  public PartDetail { get; set; }
}
```

In answer to your first comment, this is the easiest way to achieve it, the alternative is to write a custom serializer

Comment: I originally had this in my first design, looks like it may be the only answer without overriding the serializer class

Comment: Its the only way I found to do this for my situation, if your worried about having to make lots of changes to your code to make this work, you could make use of the `[XmlIgnore]` tag to provide property accessors in PartInfo to these methods in the part detail